# asp:HyperLink run-time modification

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" CssClass="RegAgenda" 
     NavigateUrl='<%#"http://www.mysite.com/store/" & 
                  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DESCRIPTION")& "?ALID=" & 
                  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"TransID")%>' 
     Target="_blank" Text="Info/Buy Now">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

In the above asp:HyperLink code, I would like to test if the current page has Chuy2 in the path and if so, change the base url to http://www.mysite2.com

how would I do that? I am a PHP guy and don't know ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"
    NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("{0}/{1}?alid={2}", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("Chuy2") ? "http://www.mysite2.com" : "http://www.mysite.com/store", Eval("Description"), Eval("TransID")) %>'
```

Comment: While this is what I want to do, I am getting this: BC36637: The '?' character cannot be used here.

Comment: I've tried changing to an If..Else but it still isn't working.

Comment: Well, you led me to the answer: `<%# string.Format("{0}/{1}?ALID={2}", If(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("Chuy2"), "http://www.mysite2.com/store","http://www.mysite.com/store"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DESCRIPTION"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"TransID")) %>`  NOTE: it took out the first http in this comment, damn I wished they'd let us post code in comments. Also added a ; after the second url in the if(), go figure.

Comment: Looks like I forgot the closing quote after the format specification. I fixed it for the sake of accuracy. Glad you figured it out though :)

Answer (score 0):

rather than try to piece this together in the markup/template, I would build the url in the code behind, or view model and then bind that value. the markup might look like this

```
NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Url")%>'
```

Comment: So you're suggesting that he iterate over the datasource in code-behind and modify the URL column? Not too sure about that approach. He could create a method or property to return the host, but I wouldn't do any more than that.

Comment: not necessarily, it depends how data is bound. I push as much logic/processing to the core of the system and let the outer layers (like codebehind/markup) be as thin as possible. makes for easy automated tests and keeps the markup simple.

Comment: I agree with those views in general, but in this case it would just obscure the logic. Sometimes it's better to compromise on that principle for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Gonna be too difficult to do this in the CodeBehind.